# How to hide slideshow images on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have created a page with a slideshow in the banner.

Everything works great- other than when the page is being loaded.
When the browser loads the page, it displays all the images, one under another, covering the entire page, and only then its start playing the slide show, hiding the rest of the images.

You can see it happening here: http://regal.preciseos.com/

I would like to prevent it from happening, and have only the first image displayed in the banner area on load.

Any advice? I can't figure it out.
Thanks,
Oz

Comment: Hide them all with css initially, possibly leaving the first one visible.

Answer (score 0):

Do one of the following:

Apply a class to each image with `display: none` on it:

```
.myClass {display: none;}

<img class="myClass" />
```

---

Add `style="display: none;"` to each image:

```
<img style="display: none;" />
```

---

Hide the images in a document.ready function:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myClass').hide();
});
```

Depending on what slider you're using, you may need to show the first image on document.ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myClass').hide().get(0).show();
});
```

But your slider plugin may do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Give CSS Like this

Let us consider the width X height  of the banner is 1366X329. Add your all images in a container

```
.container{ width:1366px; height:329px; overflow:hidden}
```

Your CSS Like this

```
.banner {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #BBB;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #bbb;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #BBB;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

height you have given auto, Please give a pixel value